# Create a repost of latest and second latest value

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have products audits table looks like this

| id | product_id | column_updated | value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product_1 | name | Big Shoes. | "18 September 2022 6:42:50 PM GMT+05:30" |
| 2. | product_1 | name | Green Shoes | "18 September 2022 6:42:43 PM GMT+05:30" |
| 3. | product_1 | name | Big Green Shoes | "18 September 2022 6:43:43 PM GMT+05:30" |

I want to show report of latest change happened on column
in form like below

| product_id | column_updated | latest_value | previous_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product_1 | name | Green Shoes | Big Green Shoes |

I have prepared a query to fetch last 2 record but not sure how I can merge them to form a view like this?

my query is

```
select product_id, column_updated, value 
from audits 
where product_id = 'product_1' 
 and column_updated = 'name' 
order by timestamp desc 
limit 2;
```

Please suggest any approach for this, Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `LEAD`a swindow function to hget the latest and previous value

```
WITH CTE as
(select product_id,
   column_updated,
   value as latest_value,
     lead(value) over (
         partition by product_id,column_updated order by timestamp desc
         ) as previous_value,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (
         partition by product_id,column_updated order by timestamp desc
         ) rn
     
    from audits 
where product_id = 'product_1' 
 and column_updated = 'name')
SELECT product_id, column_updated,latest_value,previous_value FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

| product_id | column_updated | latest_value | previous_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product_1 | name | Big Green Shoes | Big Shoes. |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C9ppB1UQ)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by combination of window functions and CTE:

```
with data as (
  select 
    product_id, 
    column_updated,
    value,
    lag(value) over (partition by product_id, column_updated order by updated_at asc) prev_value,
    row_number() over (partition by product_id, column_updated order by updated_at desc) rn,
    updated_at
 from log
) select 
    product_id, 
    column_updated,
    value,
    prev_value,
    updated_at
from data 
where rn = 1;
```

[online sql editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/bdcd011242535f0299da24f6873bfade/)

where `lag` give us previous value and `row_number` give ability to filter only last change

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both row_number and lag like the other answers.  You can do it with just row_number.  Give it a row number and then join back with the prior value having row number 2.

```
WITH rownumbered AS (
  SELECT product_id, column_updated, value, updated_at
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) rn,
  FROM log
) 
SELECT d.product_id, d,column_updated, d.value, p.value as prevous_value
FROM rownumbered d
JOIN rownumbered p ON d.product_id = p.product_id and p.rn = 2
WHERE d.rn = 1;
```

You may want to group by product_id and name -- if that is the case it looks like this:

```
WITH rownumbered AS (
  SELECT product_id, column_updated, value, updated_at
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, column_updated ORDER BY updated_at DESC) rn,
  FROM log
) 
SELECT d.product_id, d,column_updated, d.value, p.value as prevous_value
FROM rownumbered d
JOIN rownumbered p ON d.product_id = p.product_id 
                  and d.column_updated = p.column_updated
                  and p.rn = 2
WHERE d.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use lag to get the previous value? https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lag-function/

```
 select product_id,
     lag(column_updated) over (
         partition by product_id order by timestamp desc
         ) as column_updated,
    column_updated as latest_value
    from ...
```

Comment: Yes. Got that. Thanks for the solution